# Where should I open an issue for improved TSDoc support in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

We use TSDoc in our project and use tags like @inheritDoc and @link often.  These are rendered nicely on our docs site but they thwart intellisence in VS Code.

Especially @inheritDoc is a bummer because without it, VS Code automatically shows the doc comments from the base class or interface, but with it VS Code just shows a string like `{@inheritDoc IFoo.bar}`.

Would this be a feature request for the core TS Language Service, or something to work out in an extension?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to fix this?